# Git for beginners

Tags: git, version-control

Hi i have a FreeBSD server and some windows machines. I want a FreeBSD has been a central git server. On server i install git from ports with SSH support (i read that git have it own protocol and i want to use it). I modify /etc/rc.conf:

```
git_daemon_enable="YES"
git_daemon_directory="/usr/local/git/repo"
git_daemon_flags="--export-all --syslog --enable=receive-pack --listen=ip_address –verbose "
```

Do next steps:

```
$ pw user add git
$ passwd git
```

start git daemon

```
$ /usr/local/etc/rc.d/git_daemon start
```

build local repository

```
$ mkdir /usr/local/git/repo/firstbaregitrepo
$ cd /usr/local/git/repo/firstbaregitrepo
$ git init --bare --shared=true
$ chown -R git mydroid.git
$ chgrp -R git mydroid.git
```

I think that all on server side (I want to send files using git protocol)? Help me understand bare repo. 
Now i on the Windows machine. I Use Git for windows. How can i call a git clone or git pull if my server have 192.168.0.88 IP-address?

Comment: You should consider using gitolite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest looking at gitolite. But for now, you should be able to just clone like so:

```
git clone git://192.168.0.88/firstbaregitrepo
cd firstbaregitrepo
git log --all
```

You could also skip the git daemon and go straight through SSH.